# SharePoint designer 2013 workflow: Start a task process get 2 emails

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I create an approve workflow in spd 2013 by using action item "start a task process"

Testing is ok, but I got 2 emails.

One says  Task Assigned-Task name

Another one says Tasks-Task name has been assigned to you.

How can I turn off the email that generated by task and only keep one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the hardest answer to find! totally what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Go into the Workflow Tasks list and go to List Settings. Click on Advanced Settings and then set Send e-mail when ownership is assigned? to No.